# tk window doesn' t pop up

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hi I'm new to python and Tkinter. When I execute the code, nothing is happening an there isn't error. After less than one second,the code finish to process.

```
from tkinter import *
w1 = Tk()
w1.mainloop'
```

Comment: You should instantiate the `Tk` class and actually _call_ the `mainloop` method. See https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/tkinter.html

Comment: The updated code is still missing the `()` in `w1.mainloop`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you used

```
from tkinter import *
```

so tkinter.Tk isn't a thing, since tkinter isn't in the namespace, instead you must just do Tk

Also, tkinter.Tk is a class, and for it to work, needs to be instantiated. w1.mainLoop is a function, and needs to be called.
Therefore, a working code should be

```
from tkinter import *
w1 = Tk()
w1.mainloop()
```

Comment: "*there is no need to do tkinter.Tk, instead you can just do Tk*" - That statement is misleading as it appears to say: `tkinter.Tk` *would also work but it is not required as* `Tk` *is simpler*. But the reality is `tkinter.Tk` would throw a `NameError` as `tkinter` is not present in the [namespace](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/namespaces-and-scope-in-python/). To use `tkinter.Tk()`, you must first give `import tkinter`.

Comment: Right, my bad, I'll fix it

Comment: sorry , that's what i did... but so, it continue to do nothing

Comment: Would you mind sending your new modified code?

Comment: It's exactly what you do but I think that it isn't coming of the code

Comment: Just making sure, you aren't getting any errors, and the window is 100% not showing up?

Comment: exactly... I don't understand. Before, i had an error so I installed Tkinter with the terminal  and since, there isn't error but the window is not showing up and the process end

Comment: You installed it using pip? If so then did you use `pip install tk` or something else?

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: And just to be sure, you are on python 3, right? and the import is of tkinter without any capitalization?

Comment: yes i have python 3.8

Comment: Then I don't know. I suggest maybe uninstalling and reinstalling tkinter, and if it still doesn't work, maybe debug it somehow.

Comment: how do you uninstall tkinter?

Comment: `sudo apt remove python3-tk`
also, I'm not sure if it will work, but maybe when reinstalling it you can try
`sudo apt-get tk`
instead of
`sudo apt-get python3-tk`

Comment: I' so dumb... I had missing () after mainloop...Sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 1):

I believe you already fixed your typo `w1.mainloop'` to `w1.mainloop()`.
I want to recommend using `import tkinter as tk`, so you don't overwrite you namespace.

Then your code could look like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

w1 = tk.Tk()
w1.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks but i had just miss () after mainloop